# VS Code Intellisense for auto exported global variables

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, sails.js

Sails exports a set og global variables, such as:

- `_` (lodash)
- `sails` (framework related)
- `ModelOne`, `ModelTwo`, `ModelThree`, ... (the sails models we define)

Creating a jsconfig.json targeting es5 doesn't help since the variables aren't explicitly declared.

I have this variables declared on eslintrc.globals, but that just tells the linter they exist.

Ideally I'd like to have intellisense for this variables across my project.

Is there any way I can declare this global variable types in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, looking at [the npm page for sails.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails), they don't provide type declaration files, and don't have community contributed type declaration files in [the Definitely Typed project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

Your options are:

1. Contribute type declaration files to the Definitely Typed project for sails.js (see [their contributing instructions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute)), and then install your contributed types package (like `npm install -D '@types/sailjs'` (or whatever it gets called))
2. Create your own type declarations NPM package (outside of the Definitely Typed project) and use that. In that case, see [the TypeScript guide on publishing declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).
3. Create a type declaration file (`myfDeclarationFile.d.ts` or something of your choice) and define those types there. Put the file anywhere where it will be picked up as part of your project based on your tsconfig.json/jsoconfig.json file.

   Note that in this case, you might need to make sure the name of the `.d.ts` file you create might need to not have the same name as other `.ts` files in the same directory (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51128).

In your particular case, since these are type declarations for globals, see [TypeScript's guide for declaring types for global libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html). For guides for other types of libraries, see [the guide index page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html).